# set CSS on iOS devices doesn't work

Tags: html, css

This is a question regarding changing the `top` property of an element in HTML.

I am trying to build a game which pans the background image horizontally and the object in question vertically.The game works properly on the desktop but on the iPhone,the top property isn't changing dynamically.

This is the code where I am trying to set the `top`

```
blitzbot.bgPanValue.vy += blitzbot.bgPanValue.gravity;
blitzbot.bgPanValue.currentY -= blitzbot.bgPanValue.vy;
var cury = Math.round(blitzbot.bgPanValue.currentY);
document.getElementById("hotDog").style.top = -cury - 300 + "px";
```

I traced out the value of `document.getElementById("hotDog").style.top` and the values do change.However,the top is not getting set for `hotDog` on iPhone.

Best,
Harsha

Comment: Is it possible that the top attribute is being set somewhere else in the CSS?  Use Chrome inspector to see if its getting reset.

Comment: Try checking the exact value of `cury`, maybe it changes to `undefined` or `NaN`.

Comment: It works fine on chrome.The property has a problem only on iPhone.
I used `console.log` and console reports changed values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what the issue was!

There was a `background-position` property which was being used depending on some hitTests.Apparently,mobile safari has issues with `background-position` !